# Are these yellow orange hawthorns edible?

Tags: food, plants, edible

I have lots of these hawthorns in my neighborhood ([Mount Lebanon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Lebanon)) but I am afraid to eat from them. Are they safe ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worth adding the regional information to the question? Some berries change as they ripen and Crataegus come in a variety of colours https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10217/are-hawthorn-berries-edible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, it looks like typical Eurasia yellow Hawthorn. All hawthorn are edible and they do carry some cyanide in the seed like crab apple. As long as you don't swallow 100 pounds of seeds you should be fine. Found similar tree here: https://www.dreamstime.com/crataegus-yellow-berries-green-leaves-romania-hawthorn-fruits-contain-antioxidants-have-property-acting-image108044699 Looks like we are looking at same plant here. Article also stated various health benefit.

On the other hand, based on personal experience, wild hawthorn could be tart as hell....... Pit them and try make punch or jelly with them with a lot of sugar. Otherwise it will be too sour to enjoy.